# How to tell when UWP socket is disconnected?

Tags: c#, sockets, uwp

So I have this program that's using sockets with the universal windows platform. I have it setup to receive this byte from the client to turn this light off and on. Here is the bulk of the socket code.

```
    private static void AccepCallback(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        // When connection is found start receiving data for the lifetime of the program
        while (e.AcceptSocket.Connected)
        {
            // Create some socket event args
            SocketAsyncEventArgs eReceive = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

            // Create the buffer of data to be read in (with nothing in it)
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];

            // Set the buffer to the event arguments
            eReceive.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // Subscribe the event to the function Receive
            eReceive.Completed += Receive;
            if (!e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(eReceive))
                Receive(e.AcceptSocket, eReceive);
        }
    }
```

It works but I have one problem. When you exit the the client the e.AcceptSocket.Connected remains true and it is stuck in that loop forever. I'd like it to step out of that loop and continue listening for a connection in another loop. Is there a function call I need to update the flag of e.AccepSocket.Connected? Or is there an entirely different flag I should be using to tell if the client is connected to the server.

Comment: The documentation by MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs(v=vs.110).aspx suggests that you should close the socket when you receive an error on it that indicates the other side disconnected (e.SocketError enumeration here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketerror(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use somthing like this

```
while (e.AcceptSocket.Connected && e.AcceptSocket.Available > 0)
{
     // Create some socket event args
     SocketAsyncEventArgs eReceive = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();

     // Create the buffer of data to be read in (with nothing in it)
     byte[] buffer = new byte[e.AcceptSocket.Available];
     .
     .
     .
```

Comment: Socket.Available doesn't exist in uwp unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a 0 byte to the socket and check if the socket is returning **Success** or **WouldBlock**.

Try this:

```
byte[] arr = new byte[1];
SocketError se = SocketError.SocketError;
e.AcceptSocket.Send(arr, 0, 0, SocketFlags.None, out se);
bool bConnected =  ((se == SocketError.Success) || (se == SocketError.WouldBlock));
```